# push back multiple types of data in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Let's say I have a vector full of points like this:

```
vector<Point3f> cluster_points
```

Now I am getting distance between 2 points for each point in the vector. I want to store all these data in a container like below:

```
{distance, (both point's index number from *cluster_points*)}
```

e.g.

```
{70.54,  (0,1)};
{98.485, (1,2)};
{87.565, (2,3)};
{107.54, (3,4)};
```

How can I do this in C++11?

Comment: Make a simple POD struct with a float/double for distance and a pair/array for index.

Comment: Is there anything that you tried? Did you perform any research? Did you think through your problem and come up with any ideas?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I thought about it and came up with the idea to use `std::vector<std::tuple<float, std::map<size_t, size_t>>>`. But there is a small problem. I don't know how I can search for an individual element? For example, if I'll do `vector.at(4)` it will give me everything but let's I only want p1 & p1 and not distance information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++14:

```
struct DistanceBetweenPoints
{
    double distance = {};
    size_t p1 = {};
    size_t p2 = {};
};

std::vector<DistanceBetweenPoints> foo;
foo.push_back({ 70.54, 0, 1 });
//...
```

**EDIT**

Just like Khouri Giordano noted in the comments section, this isn't supported in C++11 because when using in-class initialization, it becomes a non-POD type and you lose aggregate construction. See his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45080981/2950563) for C++11 compatible solutions.

Comment: Why do you declare the variables as `= {}` ?

Comment: @Chiel It means default construction, i.e. zero.

Comment: If the types change, the initialization syntax won't (i.e. it's more generic).

Comment: If you compile this with `-std=c++11`, it will fail for lack of a constructor. This is what I've been struggling with for the last 30 minutes with my answer.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I edited my answer (even if the question wasn't tagged C++14). I assume that if mine got accepted, his compiler supports C++14 too.

Comment: But the question remains open now: what is the best way to do this in C++11?

Comment: @Chiel See Khouri Giordano answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make a structure to hold the things you want to hold. Give it appropriate constructors.

```
struct distance_indexes_t
{
    double distance;
    size_t p1, p2;

    distance_indexes_t()
        : distance(), p1(), p2()
    {}

    distance_indexes_t( double distance, size_t p1, size_t p2 )
        : distance( distance ), p1( p1 ), p2( p2 )
    {}
};
distance_indexes_t di1; // zeros
distance_indexes_t di2{ 3.5, 4, 5 };
```

**OR**

```
struct distance_indexes_t
{
    double distance = 0;
    size_t p1 = 0, p2 = 0;

    distance_indexes_t() = default; // Not necessary, but nice for clarity.

    distance_indexes_t( double distance, size_t p1, size_t p2 )
        : distance( distance ), p1( p1 ), p2( p2 )
    {}
};
distance_indexes_t di1; // zeros
distance_indexes_t di2{ 3.5, 4, 5 };
```

Both will use the default copy constructor and assignment operator. Move constructor and move operator don't matter here, but you'll get those defaults too.

Alternatively, for C++14:

```
struct distance_indexes_t
{
    double distance = 0;
    size_t p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
};
distance_indexes_t di1; // zeros
distance_indexes_t di2{ 3.5, 4, 5 };
```

Alternatively, for C++03 and earlier:

```
struct distance_indexes_t
{
    double distance;
    size_t p1, p2;
};
distance_indexes_t di1; // random content
distance_indexes_t di2{ 3.5, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: In C++11, I wouldn't declare any constructor. You can simply use aggregate initialization for POD type like this and use in-class initialization for default values.

Comment: In-class initialization is a C++11 feature, not C++14.

Comment: Yes, but then it's a non-POD in C++11 and you lose the aggregate construction.

Comment: I'd remove the version before the **OR**.  I'd also add a `distance_indexed_t()=default;` because I hate having to mentally evaluate the rules for when that constructor goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Store the data in a `std::vector<std::tuple<float, std::pair<size_t, size_t>>>`.

No need for 5 or 20 or 50 new lines of code.

Comment: While I do agree that it minimizes the amount of code, I think that it would make the code harder to read. Also, accessing elements of a tuple is a bit awkward for a trivial case like this.

Comment: Tuples are great for use in templates where you don't know the types or even how many types. For other uses, it is much clearer to create a struct.

Comment: @JérémiP.: A typedef or two will fix that

Comment: Is it possible to use two pairs instead of a tuple and a pair?

Comment: @Chiel: Yeah; don't know why I didn't

Comment: I dislike `std::pair` because it obfuscates. I have to go hunting around to see what `first` and `second` are declared as. A simple data type like I described in my answer is usually the right choice.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: I do actually like your `distance_indexes_t` (without ctors)